# Why is Firefox randomly reopening itself after quitting?

Tags: firefox, macos

I've had a strange problem that's been bugging me for awhile.  It seems that every couple times I quit Firefox, it will reopen itself automatically.  Basically:

- I'll hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
- Firefox will shut down
- the little 'open' light underneath its icon in the dock will disappear
- suddenly the FF icon will start bouncing and it will open back up

Usually when this happens, my previous session will appear to be loading but all the tabs will stay blank.  However, this is not always the case, sometimes my tabs will load.  Another thing I just noticed is that after it reopens, Firefox is 'hidden' (like when you click 'Hide Firefox' from the main menu) until I click on it.

If I quit FF a second time, it stays closed.  The next time I open FF, my original session will be restored and everything works normally.

This has happened on two different Macs for me, and my wife has occasionally seen this behavior as well.  Any ideas on what might be happening, and has anyone else had this happen?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that something is shelling out an `http://` address request. Is Firefox your default browser?

Comment: @VxJasonxV: You mean another application?  Yes FF is my default.

Comment: And it's always the same exact set of tabs? Not the set of tabs + 1 blank? (Yes, I saw the fact that the set of tabs is blank and never loads, but I'm talking about the total counts now.)

Comment: @vxjasonvx: I'll test it and get back to you next time i see it happen

Comment: @vxjasonvx: it just happened... it's apparently not always blank tabs.  this time it loaded my whole session, no extra tabs.  other weird thing is that Firefox is actually 'hidden' (like when you click 'Hide Firefox' in the menu) until I click on it.

Comment: @calavera you couldn’t come up with a simple question… :) Try -for the sake of it- trashing FFOX and redownloading the pkg. Also trash its preferences, cache, etc. Something is weird.

Comment: @Martin: I'm pretty sure I've done that before but I'll try again :P

Comment: @calavera does this happen under a new-fresh user? I bet there might be something in *yours* that is “triggering” FFOX

Comment: @Martin,@VxJasonxV: I blew away FF and installed 4.0 b8... so far so good.  I was running 3.6.x before.  We'll see if it stays working or not :P

Comment: @calavera Come back to Safari, it misses you… I use Safari/Chrome.

Comment: @Martin: I can't stand Safari... but Chrome I'm using a lot more after some convincing in chat by kyle :P

Comment: I had the same problem ! I downloaded version 3.5 for mac & it works fine for me now.

Comment: @sugar: thanks, now i know i'm not crazy... mostly :P

Comment: and... the beta does it too.  not as often, but it does it.  and chrome's flash plugin crashes every hour or so. meh.

Comment: @sugar: I'll try out 3.5, maybe that will fix it.

Comment: @sugar: 3.5 seems to be working.  apparently it's a some sort of bug that showed up in 3.6.  I'm going to follow up with this through mozilla's bug reporting.  If you switch your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @calavera - Thank you for your appreciation. Sometimes, I feel afraid while putting answers, just because I get down-votes most of the times. :) :D :) :-) B-)

Comment: Having the same problem with the last two version of FF 3 and also with FF4 even tho FF4 was a totally clean install on my Mac with a new user profile ... just extensions and bookmarks imported. Everytime I close it, it always reopens 1 more time until I quit a 2nd time. FF is NOT my dfeault browser.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Stackexchange is not like other forums. Answers to questions should actually attempt to answer the question. Otherwise, remarks such as this should be entered as a comment. I am going to convert your answer to a comment for the question itself. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem ! I downloaded version 3.5 for mac & it works fine for me now.

**Please Take Note of following.**
Even in FireFox version 3.5, I faced a strange behavior.
When I try to open a new tab sometimes it goes adding new tabs in bulk, I mean infinite loop of adding new tab. In that case, I used to quit fireFox by force. ( force-Quit ).
It happens quite frequently, even though I couldn't determine the exact steps to produce that bug. So, If you face same kind of behavior, please let me know by comments.